# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource API Gateway

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

I have an API Gateway set in AWS that is connected to lambda function, and also I have a S3 website that is trying to call the endpoints exposed by the API Gateway, CORS are enabled for S3 website but when I try to hit any of the endpoints I receive this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myapi.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://mywebsite.region.amazonaws.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I already set permissions and cors in the S3 website but looks like is not working, this is my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://mywebsite.region.amazonaws.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>30000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I also try `<AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>` but did not work, has anyone face and fix this issue in the past?

Comment: in this case, you need to set CORS on API gateway side since it's the backend sharing resources.

Comment: Have you enabled [corse for lambda on api gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)?

Comment: Yes, I already enabled CORS for api gateway and having same result

Comment: Might be a silly question, but did you deploy your resources after you enabled CORS?

Comment: Yes, I deployed my resources after I enabled CORS

Answer (score -1):

So after a good research, I follow [this](https://enable-cors.org/server_awsapigateway.html) guide to enable cors in my API Gateway and is working now and also I had to change the integration between the methods and the lambda function, I was using lambda proxy integration and looks like that config gives problems (lack of experience here) but now is working fine, thanks all for your comments!

**UPDATE**

I had another issue when I tried to the first solution that I posted here, then I go back to `Proxy Integration Lambda` and continue with my research, I had to apply more changes to the lambda function that expose the `GraphQL Server`

This is how it looks now:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    playground: {
        endpoint: "/api/graphql"
    },
    context: ({ event, context }) => ({
        headers: event.headers,
        functionName: context.functionName,
        event,
        context,
    }),
});

exports.graphqlHandler = server.createHandler({
    cors: {
        origin: '*',
        credentials: true,
    },
});
```

With that config my server works fine without any `CORS` issues.